Cannot find module 'xxx' when referencing javascript from typescript
I am trying to integrate javascript code into my typescript project.
I have the following in my javascript file "oldProcessing.js":
export async function process(myphone) {
...
}
...
module.exports = { process };

I have the following in my global.d.ts file located in "src/types":
declare module "oldProcessing" {
    export function process(myphone: string): any;
    // You can define more functions and types here as needed
}

I have the following in my typescript file process-location.ts located in "src/lib/tasks":
import { process } from "oldProcessing";

Finally, this is my ts.config file:
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "outDir": "lib",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "strict": true,
    "target": "ES6",
    "typeRoots": ["./node_modules/@types", "./src/types"],
    "resolveJsonModule": true
  },
  "compileOnSave": true,
  "include": ["src"]
}

This is all set up per all the documentation I've read, but I get the following each time I deploy:
Error: Cannot find module 'oldProcessing'
Require stack:

/github/workspace/functions/lib/tasks/process-location.js

